# How do I get the video I inserted to show up on my page?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I've been trying to get this video to show up on my webpage but all that's showing up are the controls and not the actual video. The whole webpage is a WIP atm but I just need to get the video to work and play in a loop. Many of the HTML is messed up, but here's the code.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="me.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Layoonie</title>
  </head>
  <h1>L A Y O O N I E</h1>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks">Bloop</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Bleep</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Blop</button>
  </div>

  <div id="Bloop" class="tabcontent">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div id="Bleep" class="tabcontent">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div id="Blop" class="tabcontent">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <video width="1280" height="720" controls>
<source src="/Users/Ummlynn/Documents/Graphic Design/Lynn.mov" type="video/mov">

</video>

</html>
```

Comment: Check docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="me.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Layoonie</title>
  </head>
  <h1>L A Y O O N I E</h1>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks">Bloop</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Bleep</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Blop</button>
  </div>

  <div id="Bloop" class="tabcontent">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div id="Bleep" class="tabcontent">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div id="Blop" class="tabcontent">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <video width="1280" height="720" controls>
<source src="https://tutorialehtml.com/assets_tutorials/media/Shaun-the-Sheep-The-Movie-Official-Trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>

</html>
```